# How to do RHEL AWS EC2 instance inplace upgrade

Tags: rhel, amazon-ec2

We have AWS ec2 instance with RHEL 8.2 OS using a public redhat ami image. Need to understand if its possible to do an inplace upgrade of the EC2 instance from RHEL 8.2 to RHEL 8.6. If yes, what are the exact steps that need to follow. Do we need to add any repositories specific for RHEL 8.6 before the upgrade process.

NOTE: The RHEL instance are not registered with Redhat yet and we are not managing the repositories using subscription manager

Tried searching the AWS docs but could not find any relevant information particular to RHEL upgrade for AWS EC2 instance. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-update-red-hat-enterprise-linux-tvia-minor-releases-and-extended-update-support) is the procedure from RedHat how to upgrade between minor versions.

Points to consider:

- Updating to the very latest software
- Sticking with a specific minor release
- Using EUS to stick with a minor release for longer